# "Fireblob" in KO₂ and PCl₅ reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, combustion, solid-state-chemistry

The reaction between $\ce{KO2(s)}$ and $\ce{PCl5(s)}$ leads to the strange formation of a black "fireblob" which eventually turns orange.

This is demonstrated in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drQQ41st7hs&t=315s) (screenshots below) but no complete explanation is given.

How is the fireblob formed?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my best guess at the play-by-play.

$\ce{PCl5}$ is a solid with a relatively low melting point (160 °C) and high volatility (sublimes at 167 °C). When the solid $\ce{KO2}$ gets dropped on the $\ce{PCl5}$, the solids don't really interact much (two solids in contact only need to touch on as little as three points, after all). However, there is some amount of $\ce{PCl5}$ vapor surrounding the solid, and some of that accidentally bumps onto the surface of the $\ce{KO2}$ above it. Reaction of the vapor and the surface is almost immediate, ultimately forming $\ce{KCl}$ and $\ce{P4O10}$, though the detailed process involves a number of intermediates such as oxychlorides and is likely fairly complicated. It also evolves a prodigious amount of heat.

Well, that heat quickly gets absorbed by the $\ce{PCl5}$, which evaporates more, feeding the reaction further. The temperature rises enough that the $\ce{PCl5}$ begins to melt locally and can spread over the surface of the $\ce{KO2}$. There's no going back now. The temperature rises very quickly, likely to ~600-800 °C, above the melting point of $\ce{KO2}$ at 560 °C. The $\ce{KO2}$ also melts, and any reaction products of the surface of the crystals which could be a physical barrier towards reaction are now mixed into the liquid, exposing fresh $\ce{KO2}$ for reaction. The heat and mixing eventually spread over the entire sample of $\ce{KO2}$, forming a large molten blob.

Let's pause here for a bit. $\ce{KO2}$ is bright yellow, and $\ce{PCl5}$ is an even lighter colour, so why is this blob black? It's difficult to say exactly what chemistry is going on such a short timespan and high temperature because these are rather out-of-equilibrium conditions, but it's quite likely that one way or another (either as a reaction intermediate, or from the thermal decomposition of $\ce{KO2}$, or straight up thermal excitation), some electrons are being knocked loose from the superoxide anions ($\ce{O2^-}$) and becoming free in the bulk of the molten droplet. Free electrons are quite short-lived in most chemical systems, but in certain situations they can be stabilized briefly. The classic example is solutions of [free electrons in liquid ammonia](https://youtu.be/gHokrNS1ask?t=680s), whereby adding a tiny speck of a silvery-white metal into a clear colourless liquid immediately generates a deep black-blue solution.

But the reaction isn't done, there's still $\ce{KO2}$ inside that molten blob, and it continues to react faster and faster. The temperature rises to as much as around 1000 °C, at which point black-body radiation starts to pump out visible photons, mostly in the red-orange part of the spectrum. The glow is due to this physical process, rather than directly due to a chemical change. As it heats further the reactions accelerate, but we avoid a finite-time singularity because the rate at which photons carry away the reaction energy [increases as $T^4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law). This creates a very strongly limiting factor for further temperature increases, so from the colour of the blob, it likely doesn't go further than roughly 2000 °C.

By this stage, the reaction is starting to peter out - almost all the $\ce{KO2}$ (the limiting reagent) has been consumed. As the last bits react, the temperature of the surface lowers to the point that the black-body photons dip back into the infrared, and the red-orange glow becomes weaker and weaker. The drop becomes black again, showing the last few free electrons. These eventually react with additional $\ce{PCl5}$, and the black colour disappears. Interestingly, the droplets generally begin glowing again, but this is not because they are significantly reheating - the interior of the droplet was still at 1000+ C, but the visible photons being radiated from the inside were being absorbed by the free electrons on the surface (it's black because it absorbs light, after all). Now that the free electrons are completely gone, the opaque medium becomes transparent, and the photons generated inside shine through. This quickly cools off the interior, and now finally, with no additional energy to be generated, everything cools down. No more reactions, just the almost-colourless remnants, still hot enough to be molten, forming transparent droplets of mostly $\ce{KCl}$ which will eventually solidify.